# Format elasticsearch result

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using Elasticsearch to retrieve a few logs:

http:/localhost:9200/collection/_search?q=type:"log"

It brings me a few hits like this:

```
        {
                "_index": "collection",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "UL878GMBYKUUOvfyQJWl",
                "_score": 6.487114,
                "_source": {
                    "@version": "1",
                    "type": "log",
                    "message": "64.242.88.10;[07/Mar/2004:16:11:58 -0800];"GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/WikiSyntax HTTP/1.1\"; 200 7352\r",
                    "@timestamp": "2018-06-11T19:03:23.163Z",
                    "host": "logstash",
                    "path": "/opt/access_log.log"
                }
            }
```

Each hit has a "message", that is like a line from a CSV "access_log.log".

But every info useful is inside "message" as only one big String. So I need to extract somehow to identify the server IP (64.242.88.10) for example.

How can I split this "message" string using ";" as regex so that I can get only the data I need?

Comment: you need to use `grok` filter https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [grok filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) for that.

> Grok is a great way to parse unstructured log data into something
>   structured and queryable.
>
> This tool is perfect for syslog logs, apache and other webserver logs,
>   mysql logs, and in general, any log format that is generally written
>   for humans and not computer consumption.
>
> Logstash ships with about 120 patterns by default. You can find them
>   here:
>   https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/tree/master/patterns.
>   You can add your own trivially. (See the patterns_dir setting)
>
> If you need help building patterns to match your logs, you will find
>   the http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com and
>   http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/ applications quite useful!